# How to quickly see if all items in list of Primary Keys exist prior to bulk_create call?

Tags: python, django

I'm attempting to do a django `bulk_create` for a list of objects. However, every so often one of the objects in the `bulk_create` already exists (it's primary key has already been allocated) so an exception is raised and no objects get created. To fix this I added a loop over each of the new objects to test if they exist prior to the `bulk_create` call but this feels very inefficient. Is there way to accomplish the same result in fewer queries to the database?

Comment: How do you manage to have duplicate ids?

Comment: There is an existing ID that serves as a primary key of the external system I'm reading from. I'm re-using that ID for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get all records from your database once. Then check if there are any duplicates. Eliminate them and do bulk create.
2. Depends on what database you are using. If for example you are using Oracle, then maybe there are options with custom PL/SQL procedures you can create. I don't know PL/SQL though, I am just sure that if it is a language, then there must be options...

Comment: I'm using Postgres and I have about 200k elements so reading them all is starting to become infeasible.

Comment: Postgres has its own PL/SQL. Maybe you should try to write a procedure, that would check ids, throw exceptions and etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is feasible directly with the Django Queryset API if you are in a recent Django version.

From Django 2.2, `bulk_create` includes a parameter called `ignore_conflicts` that would continue the execution of the `bulk_create` when an error is found.

This saves you having to do any extra queries. You can check the docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.bulk_create